# How to convert and save a Print Document to a PDF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pdf, printing

I have a Print Document called `Report`, which I'm generating in my code behind (C#) and printing it, in my WPF application.

Now I would want to save this `Report` as a PDF for future printing or any other use.

I've read about PDFSharp and XPS, but unsure, if they will help here, as my document is printed directly, and not being saved as a XPS. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at iText7. It's a powerful suite for generating, editing and working with pdf documents.

You can easily generate documents using iText. I'll show an example in java, but the c# code is exactly the same (aside from system IO).

```
File outputFile = new File("output.pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputFile));
Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph("Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"));

layoutDocument.close();
pdfDocument.close();
```

Check out other tutorials on the website http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples-itext7

Comment: Actually, I would prefer a solution, where I would not have to make the pdf again, and have it generated based on my print document itself.

Comment: The way I see it, there are 2 options. Either you start from some data somewhere (SQL, XML, plain text, ...). In which case you can simply have an interface IReportGenerator which generates some kind of output based on the data (either a pdf using iText, or a WPF). Or you work only with WPF files, in which case any software you'll want to use needs to be able to understand your WPF format. And you'll end up having to write a lot of bridge-code yourself to make sure these formats (PDF and WPF) can "speak to eachother".

Comment: Not familiar with those, can you help me start?